# How to get each day number of a month in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to get a select with each day number of a month? For example I have this date: 2021-12-15 and I want to get this result:

```
| Days| 
|--------| 
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
```

.. 31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple recursive CTE to generate a list of numbers and `eomonth()` for the days in the given date:

```
declare @date date='20211215';

with d as (
    select 1 num
    union all
    select d.num + 1
    from d
    where d.num <= 31
)
select num as [Days]
from d
where num<=Day(EOMonth(@date));
```

Comment: Ha, I was actually just typing almost this same answer leveraging EOMONTH(). Unfortunately a recursive CTE is not very performant but if we're talking days in a month, the size of the range is pretty limited so it should be okay. Too bad that `GENERATE_SERIES()` seems to be specific to Postgres.

Comment: I would typically use a tally/numbers table depending on usage, but for days in a month there will be no noticable difference and it serves to illustrate the method.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, there is an easier method.

A direct `SELECT ...` from a system table.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @date DATE ='2021-12-15';

SELECT DISTINCT number AS [Days]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND DAY(EOMonth(@date));
```